# There are 16 chess players, how many games occur, if every player should play against another each one time?

Tags: combinatorics

My thought was, that we have in general $16 \cdot 16$ games and then we should subtract $1+2+3+4+\ldots 16$ from it because if you take for example the first game: player $1$ has $15$ opponents, if take player $2$ there $14$ new, because $1$ vs $2$ is mentioned before. And so it should go on until player $16$.

As a result I have $120$, -> $16^2-1-2-3-4-\ldots -16 = 120$.

Is that right? Or is there a shorter solution?

Comment: There are $\binom{16}{2}$ pairs of players possible.

Comment: Each player has $15$ opponents, but that counts each game twice.

Comment: I could never play chess against myself. So it is $16\cdot 15$. And two players can play one with White and the other with Black, or the other way around. If you want to count both possibilities is $16\cdot 15$, otherwise is $16\cdot15/2$.

Comment: You could say player $1$ has $15$ opponents, player $2$ has $14$ and so forth to get the answer is $1+2+\cdots+15$. This is the same as the other two suggested methods [see triangular numbers] of doing this which both give $(15*16)/2$.

Answer (score 2):

There ${16 \choose 2} = 120$ games.  Count the edges in the complete graph $K_{16}$ (if you've got lots of time!):

[image: Complete graph K16]

Or... just think about this triangle for a bit:

[image]

Comment: Nice picture! Although I highly doubt anyone would actually count the edges. :)